# Oracle Collation To SQL Server Collation During Migration

Tags: sql-server, oracle, collation

I am in the process of upgrading an Oracle DB to SQL Server. Currently the Oracle DB's collation is set to WE8ISO8859P1 (binary case sensitive Eastern European character set that allows for double byte characters).  Can anyone point me to what SQL Server collation will be closest to this?

Thanks!

Clay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option normally would be to use the SQL Server default collation (SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS).  If you have data that is constrained as unique but would be duplicated (cause violations) when case insensitive (SQL Default where Oracle is case sensitive) then you will either need to update your data to be case insensitive or choose a case sensitive collation.